# Avoiding warnings while creating Windows drivers

Tags: c, windows, driver

I am working on a Windows 10 driver in Visual Studio and at the moment my driver only has a blank `DriverEntry` and a `DriverUnload` function without anything else besides from some native header include statements.

```
static void NTAPI DriverUnload(PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(DriverObject);
}

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(_In_ PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, _In_ PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(DriverObject);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(RegistryPath);

    DriverObject->DriverUnload = DriverUnload;

    return 0;
}
```

Now when reading through my driver's properties I noticed while hovering over the `C Language Standard` setting located under the C/C++ tab that is said it recommended me using the latest version of C which is /std:c17. However, when switching to this standard and trying to compile I suddenly received an error originating from wdm.h which stated `found 'L#_exp 'in macro replacment list, did you mean 'L""#_exp'?`. This was just a warning C5104 but it was also treated as an error so my driver could not be compiled.

Now my question is, is this warning valid or is not an actual issue? If it's not an issue, how can I disable this error from my properties section. My second question is if the modern version of C is actually better for KMDF drivers since I dont want to be battling with random errors all the time. I ask this because the legacy version of C does not produce any errors or warning and everything runs fine. So, what should I do in this situation?